# How to add package in such a way that program does'nt crash

Tags: java, eclipse, cmusphinx

What happens is that if i add all the libraries up along with helloworld.jar, it works. But as soon as i add a new class and make it add the code:

```
package edu.cmu.sphinx.demo.helloworld;
```

and then there is a error on it so i click it and click on move... thats the point where everything stops working. What i am trying to do is make it in a way that i am able to edit everything and then after trying, i can finally add it to my main project of java.

How to go about it?

Comment: you didn't accept answer of your last question, if it was answered

Comment: @JigarJoshi did it right now(sorry i had forgotten), can you help me on this one?

Comment: it looks like it is missing jars in classpath, and looks like common error specifically for this library after googling

Comment: But how could that have had happened when I could already have run the program once...?